# Python Pandas - KeyError: 'username' : when username exist its showing key error when I am Trying to slice users data from csv who logged in

Tags: python, pandas, csv, slice, keyerror

I am a beginner in python and working with python pandas.
I have created a program a demo of payment gateway system .
It contains a login page and signup page .
I want to display the main page when valid user logs in
after that I want to extract the data of the only valid user
in the form of Data Frame for a Function To display their profile  Containing ( Name ,Email, Phone no.) but facing this error.

This Function Executes after the login of valid user

```
def Home():
            print(1," : Profile")
            print(2," : Top-up")
            print(3," : Account Balance")
            print(4," : About us")
            print(5," : Back")
            
            print("")
            pref=int(input("Enter your Choice : "))
            print("")
            
        
            if pref==1:
                p_csv=pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
                a=p_csv.loc["username"]==["user"]
                print(a)
```

Output :

```
KeyError: 'username'
```

The Csv File Contains Certain Data and I want to extract the  user logged in the system (Only a Single row of csv containing the user data)

CSV File :

```
username,password,Name,email,Phone
Ramesh,Ramesh123,Ramesh Chaurasiya,rams@gmail.com,1234567890
pooja0,Pja125,Pooja Sharma,abc@gmail.com,7894561230
```

I was expecting it to display the Data frame containing users (name , email, phone)

I also Faced multiple errors While changing this code
like

1. length not match (2,1) (1,) ...
2. df empty[]
   only showing column names: username, password , name , email , phone
   index[]
3. keyError: 'username'

**Below here is the whole code of the program ......**

```
import pandas as pd



#functions(): All Functions are here represented ......


#====================================================================================================


def Return():
    return Main_Menu()

    

#=================================================================================================================


def Main_Menu():
   
    print("")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------")                  
    print("                ........... Main Menu ...........            ")
    print("-------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("")





    print(1,": New user")                               
    print(2,": Log-In")
    print(3,": Exit")
    
    print("")
        
    inp=int(input("===> Enter your Choice:  "))
        
    if inp==1:
        Sign_Up()
        
        
    if inp==2:
        login()
        
    if inp==3:
        print("Thanks for visiting...")
        
    
        
    

#========================================================================================                    
def Main_page():
        while True:
        
            print("")
            print("--------------------------------------------------------------------")
            print("                .........Welcome To /\/[(O).........                ")
            print("--------------------------------------------------------------------")
            print("")
            
            print(1,": Home")
            print(2,": Transaction")
            print(3,": Account Statement")
            print(4,": Exit")
            
            print("")
            choice=int(input("Enter your preference from above options: "))
            print("")
            
            
            
            if choice==1:
                print("")
                print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
                print("               ............. Home ............                     ")
                print("-------------------------------------------------------------------")
                print("")
                Home()
                    
            if choice==2:
                Transaction()
                    
            if choice==3:
                Statement()
                
            if choice==4:
                print("Returning Back...")
                
            break    
            
    
    
   
#====================================================================================================
#profile #top-up #acc_balance  #about us 


   

def Home():
            print(1," : Profile")
            print(2," : Top-up")
            print(3," : Account Balance")
            print(4," : About us")
            print(5," : Back")
            
            print("")
            pref=int(input("Enter your Choice : "))
            print("")
            
        
            if pref==1:
               p_csv=pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
               user_= "match_uname"
               a=p_csv.query("username == @user_")
               print(a)             
            
 #  ======>    This is the place where i am facing Errors
                        
            if pref==2:
                print("Top up")
                    
               
                    
            if pref==3:
                print("Balance")
                    
                
            if pref==4:
                print("About us")
                    
            if pref==5:
                Main_page()
                    
           
   
    
    
    
               
    
         
                
              
            
    
   
    
          
#===================================================================================

def Transaction():
    
    while True:
        print("")
    
    else:
        Main_page()
        
    
#====================================================================================    
    
    
def Statement():
    print("stateee")
    
#====================================================================================
def Sign_Up():

    
    _name=input("Enter your Full-Name: " )
    E_mail=input("Enter your E-mail: " )
    print("")
    print("Warning: Enter the username and password of 8 alphanumeric Digits  (**)  ---->")
    print("")
    n_user=input("Create Username: ")
    n_passwd=input("Create Password: ")
    mobile=int(input("Enter your mobile no.: "))
    
    user_data={"username":[n_user],"password":[n_passwd],"Name":[_name],"email":[E_mail],"Phone":[mobile]}
    user_cred=pd.DataFrame(user_data)
    user_cred.to_csv('Data.csv',mode='a',index=True,header=0)
    
        
    

    
    
    print("")
    print("======Account Successfully Created======")
    Return()
    
    
#===================================================================================================   
    
def login():
    log_cred=pd.read_csv('Data.csv')  # Reading csv File..
    print("")
    print("======= LOGIN  ============")    
    print("")
    
    user=input('username: ')
    passwd=input('password: ')
                                       # input data taken from user...                                   
   
    match_uname=log_cred.loc[log_cred["username"]==user]
    
              # comparing the data given by user == True or False/...
  
#================================================================================================   
#                      ......All Function Execution Window........
#==========================================================================================================

 #login Execution....
   
    if match_uname.empty:
        print("")
        print("Oops! Invalid Username `\(*_*)")
        print("")
        return False
      
    else:
        match_pass=log_cred.loc[log_cred["password"]==passwd]
        
        if match_pass.empty:
            print("")
            print("Invalid Password \(@_@)..Oops!")
            print("")
            return False
            
        else:
            print("")
            print("Valid username and password...<(~_~)>...Welcome")
            print("")
            Main_page()
                
            return True
            
   
        
        
        
        
#================================================================================================== 


#Main menu execution ....

print("")
print("")    
a=input("Press Enter ...")  
 
if a=="":
    Main_Menu()
    
else:
    print("Get lost")
```

Comment: Hello Dikshant,

I think I am missing the point here. If you select ['username'] you will be returned with a Series object (a collection of values).

So for example, if you change your code to:

a=p_csv.loc[:, "username"]==["user"]

You will encounter the error ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (2,), (1,))

Can you please give out some more information? 

What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I am creating a demo payment gateway in which I validated the user (theirs a login form ) if their is a valid user who enter correct username & password the main menu will be executed that contains home transaction and statement . In the home option I want to display the users personal details like their [name ,email, phone  Etc ] so I want to slice the users acc. details from the csv file who logged in and display his personal details in the home functions profile menu

Answer (score 0):

```
user = "Ramesh"
a = p_csv.query("username == @user")
print(a)

  username   password               Name           email       Phone
0   Ramesh  Ramesh123  Ramesh Chaurasiya  rams@gmail.com  1234567890
```

Comment: Sir Thank you very much for Responding on my query. but I took user credentials  ( username & password in the login function ) and the user varies from one another depending upon which user logged in and I want to display account details of a specific user who logged in from csv ...                                  
                                                                     I have edited the above code and given the whole program please evaluate and help .